# How to set Susy gutter width to be more than 1 column

Tags: susy, susy-sass

I'm using with-layout to temporarily set defaults for my page column structure.  I need a 24 column grid to allow finer control, but need a gutter that's larger than 1 column.  Is that possible?

```
@include with-layout(24) {
    .col-1 {
        @include span(17);
    }
    .col-2 {
        @include span(7);
    }
}
```

So something like `@include with-layout(24 2col-gutter) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that if you want the gutter to be a multiple of the column width (1 col, 2 col etc) then you can just use the pre and push options.

In my case I actually wanted the gutter to be twice the width of the column so this worked perfectly.

```
$susy: (
  columns: 24,
  gutters: 0
);

.col-1 {
  @include span(17);
}

.col-2 {
  @include span(5);
}

.col-1 + .col-2 {
  @include pre(2);
}
```

[Demo](http://sassmeister.com/gist/4caeb6233dbbaa927dd9)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$my-layout: (
  columns: 24,
  gutters: 2,
);

@include with-layout($my-layout) {
  .col-1 {
      @include span(17);
  }
 .col-2 {
     @include span(last 7);
 }
}
```

If you want more or less gutter-space change the number of gutters.

Comment: That doesn't seem to set the gutter to 2 columns.  It's still a ratio of 1 column I think. Maybe 2/4 so half a column?

Comment: You can see it here [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/32f0b641baf69a2cb573)

Comment: I'm not really sure what that number is doing.  12 sets the margin to 4% but if you increased it to 200 then the margin is 4.32526%.  That doesn't seem to correlate so I'm trying to work out what that number actually means.